# How to delete from cursor until end of line with VS or Power Tool

Tags: visual-studio-2010, editor, productivity-power-tools

In VS2010, how can I delete from the cursor position until the end of the line.  I once read about such a shortcut, but now cannot find it.

Comment: in 2018, macOS Visual Studio Code, Control+K Work for me

Comment: Confirming in 2021 that Ctrl + K works for the specified purpose.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The Editor Command is called `Edit.DeleteToEOL` You can see it in the Tools --> Options --> Environment --> Keyboard Dialog. There is no predefined keyboard shortcut assigned to it, but Visual Studio gives you the option of creating one.

[image]

Comment: I tried to add Ctrl-K (ex-emacs user!) but it sits there waiting for the next key-press. Any suggestions?

Comment: @James Ctrl-K is used for chording in visual studio that is the reason why it waits, if you try to assign it you will see all of the shortcuts that use it in the `Shortcut currently used by` combobox. If you do not use any of those you could remove the shortcuts or reassign them, which should allow it to work how you want it to.

Comment: This works, but sadly doesn't delete a blank line like it would in macOS

Comment: Just an FYI - in newer versions of Visual Studio the preset for this is Ctrl + K, Ctrl + E

Answer (score 13):

Visual Studio doesn't have key combination to delete from cursor to end line.

I use <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>End</kbd> and <kbd>Delete</kbd>.

Answer (score 2):

10 years have passed on this one. I am running VSCode v1.64.2 on a macbook and `control+k` will delete from your cursor to the end of a line.

Comment: Just an FYI to this. If you use any extension which uses the ^K+ prefix keybinding, the default control+k will not work. For me, it was the workspace explorer extension. I deleted the keybindings of the extension, and control+k has started working again.

Comment: One and a half year has passed (v1.83) and ctrl+K deletes the entire line (on Linux). Has anybody happen to know the shortcut to delete "from cursor until end of line" and the reverse "from cursor until beginning"?

Comment: `control+k` - Delete to the end of the line --- `control+u` Delete to the beginning of line

Comment: Not working in VSCode 1.84.2 :(

Answer (score 1):

2024 : You can bind to "Delete all right" :

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxHY5.png)